# UWP Localization of external ClassLibrary

Tags: c#, localization, win-universal-app

I'm struggeling to make my ClassLibrary localized.
I create a new project Type ClassLibrary for UWP. I want to make my own ClassLibrary for my own projects.

To get the different resources I used following code I've found in the web:

```
namespace JCDesign
{
public static class LocalizedNamesLibrary
{
    static ResourceLoader resourceLoader = null;

    public static string LibraryName
    {
        get
        {
            string name;
            GetLibraryName("string1", out name);
            return name;
        }
    }

    private static void GetLibraryName(string resourceName, out string resourceValue)
    {
        if (resourceLoader == null)
        {
            resourceLoader = ResourceLoader.GetForViewIndependentUse("JCDesign/resources");
        }
        resourceValue = resourceLoader.GetString(resourceName);
    }
}
}
```

When I add the ClassLibrary to my Solution (e.g. the App I'm working on), all is fine.

But if I add a reference to the dll only (Add Reference/Browse/...) I run into errors "ResourceMap not found)
Before I add the reference I've build the ClassLibrary...

Can you help me? I really don't know what to to, or if my steps are the right ones

Thank you

Comment: It isn't very external by the time your AppX package is built.  The class library and its resources needs to be merged into the package.  The exception says that this did not happen correctly.  Its never been very obvious to me how to do this correctly, the path of least resistance is to add the project to the solution and use a project reference.

Comment: Thank you... I'll do it that way...